# web application throwing error in iis

Tags: asp.net, iis-8

I am using one asp.net application which i hosted as website in iis. After that i added one another web application under of that website. Both are working there i did not find any issue. Later i added one custom http module in website for urlrewrite then checked it is working fine. But now the issue is when i am running web application then it is throwing error.
Please see the screen shot below:
[Screen shot for error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKhTo.png)

Comment: Make sure the Fortius.dll is present in required folder, there would be some other dll being used by Fortius.dll missing. So you should know what dlls are required by Fortius.dll

Comment: As i have mentioned in the above question i have one website which dll is fortius.cms and another is web application both are seprate project. so there is no dependency on each other.

Comment: You said "After that i added one another web application under of that website" 

That means your application would be at same level the other website is. Create empty website and add two applications in it to make them independent.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by my own. just need to add remove httpmodule name in web application web.config under   and it works fine for me.